# How can I make my header image properly responsive?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am trying to put a site together for a friend using a really nice premium Wordpress theme. I have paid for the theme but the designer will not help with customisation.

The site is currently at [www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/test/](http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/test/). Originally the theme had a small left-aligned logo but my friend favours this large full-width one, which I think works better. Problem is now that I look at it on an iPad or iPhone (portrait) the logo is too big and screws it up. In the theme options it is defined as 922px width and 168px height. I cannot put a percentage value in there. Can I override this in CSS somewhere?

Any help would be gratefully received as I am a bit out of my depth.

Answer (score 6):

try using `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` this should resize the image properly.

Comment: I can't find where to change this, except in the theme control panel, and in there it only accepts px values, not %. I cannot find the 922px background-size value in the style.css so i guess it has to be in the php and i know NOTHING about php... thanks for trying though!

Comment: It would have but it's a background image, not inline.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to deal with it is to insert the logo image inline rather than as a background image. That way you can apply CSS to the img element itself;

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo-container"><a href="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/test"><img src="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/wide-logo-2.png" alt="" /></a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo-container img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks McNab! That makes perfect sense even to me. Problem is this is a Wordpress them so I can't edit the html. It's all that horrible php stuff I think, although I can edit style.css

Comment: Just go into the theme and edit `header.php`.  The code for the logo is in there, replace it with what I have put above and remove the inline style for the #logo-container a background image `#logo-container a{background:url('http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/wide-logo-2.png') no-repeat;}`

Comment: Pretty sure I have done all of that no but no joy. Thanks ever so much for your efforts. I am sure you are right and I am somehow messing it up this end. Everything looks fine everywhere else it's still just that the image is too big in portrait mode on my iPad. Damn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following media condition in css

```
 /* Resize Background*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    #header{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            background-size: 100% auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still no joy! I tried it exactly as you have it there and also with #logo-container instead of #header. I pasted it at the bottom of the style.css.

Answer (score 1):

Try to style the image, not the link.

```
logo-container img {
width: 100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using % instead of px. This way, your image will scale with page size.

In your HTML, you could try something like

```
<img src="logo.png" width="80%" height="80%"/>
```

This would scale with screen width. Of course, you want to scale the height as well to preserve aspect ratio.

FYI, the site looks fine on my Android phone when I zoom out all the way.

Comment: I have changed width and height to 100% in every instance of "logo-container a" that I can find. It makes no difference. I think that the reference to the actual .png file is buried in php somewhere. Tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#logo-container img {
   width: 100%; !important
   height: auto; !important
}
```

It will overwrite the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

How image gets zoomed on hover?

Here is the sample html:

```
<footer>
              <!-- Main Footer -->
              <section class="section background-dark">
                  <div class="line">
                      <div class="margin">
                          <!-- Column 1 -->
                          <div class="s-12 m-12 l-4 margin-m-bottom-2x">
                              <h4 class="text-uppercase text-strong">Our Philosophy</h4>
                              <p class="text-size-20"><em>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt."</em><p>

                                  <div class="line">
                                      <h4 class="text-uppercase text-strong margin-top-30">About Our Company</h4>
                                      <div class="margin">
                                          <div class="s-12 m-12 l-4 margin-m-bottom">
                                              <a class="image-hover-zoom" href="/"><img src="img/blog-04.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="s-12 m-12 l-8 margin-m-bottom">
                                               <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.</p>
                                               <a class="text-more-info text-primary-hover" href="/">Read more</a>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                         </div>

                  <!-- Column 2 -->
                     <div class="s-12 m-12 l-4 margin-m-bottom-2x">
                      <h4 class="text-uppercase text-strong">Contact Us</h4>
                      <div class="line">
                          <div class="s-1 m-1 l-1 text-center">
                              <i class="icon-placepin text-primary text-size-12"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-11 m-11 l-11 margin-bottom-10">
                              <p><b>Adress:</b> Responsive Street 7, London, UK</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="line">
                          <div class="s-1 m-1 l-1 text-center">
                              <i class="icon-mail text-primary text-size-12"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-11 m-11 l-11 margin-bottom-10">
                              <p><a href="/" class="text-primary-hover"><b>E-mail:</b> contact@sampledomain.com</a></p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="line">
                          <div class="s-1 m-1 l-1 text-center">
                              <i class="icon-smartphone text-primary text-size-12"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-11 m-11 l-11 margin-bottom-10">
                              <p><b>Phone:</b> 0700 000 987</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="line">
                          <div class="s-1 m-1 l-1 text-center">
                              <i class="icon-twitter text-primary text-size-12"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-11 m-11 l-11 margin-bottom-10">
                              <p><a href="/" class="text-primary-hover"><b>Twitter</b></a></p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="line">
                          <div class="s-1 m-1 l-1 text-center">
                              <i class="icon-facebook text-primary text-size-12"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-11 m-11 l-11">
                              <p><a href="/" class="text-primary-hover"><b>Facebook</b></a></p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Column 3 -->
                       <div class="s-12 m-12 l-4">
                      <h4 class="text-uppercase text-strong">Leave a Message</h4>
                      <form class="customform text-white">
                          <div class="line">
                              <div class="margin">
                                  <div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
                                      <input name="email" class="required email border-radius" placeholder="Your e-mail" title="Your e-mail" type="text" />
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
                                      <input name="name" class="name border-radius" placeholder="Your name" title="Your name" type="text" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-12">
                              <textarea name="message" class="required message border-radius" placeholder="Your message" rows="3"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class="s-12"><button class="submit-form button background-primary border-radius text-white" type="submit">Submit Button</button></div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
              </section>
              <hr class="break margin-top-bottom-0" style="border-color: rgba(0, 38, 51, 0.80);">

              <!-- Bottom Footer -->
              <section class="padding background-dark">
                  <div class="line">
                      <div class="s-12 l-6">
                          <p class="text-size-12">Copyright 2019, Vision Design - graphic zoo</p>
                          <p class="text-size-12">All images have been purchased from Bigstock. Do not use the images in your website.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="s-12 l-6">
                          <a class="right text-size-12" href="http://www.myresponsee.com" title="Responsee - lightweight responsive framework">Design and coding<br> by Responsee Team</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
          </footer>
```

Here is part of css:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    color: #777;
}
.text-primary, .text-primary *, .primary-color-primary .text-primary, .primary-color-primary .text-primary * {
    color: #49BF4C !important;
}
.text-primary-hover:hover, .primary-color-primary .text-primary-hover:hover {
    color: #49BF4C !important;
}
.text-white, .text-white *, .primary-color-white .text-primary, .primary-color-white .text-primary * {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.background-primary, .primary-color-primary .background-primary {
    background-color: #49BF4C !important;
}
.margin-bottom-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    display: block;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .margin-m-bottom {
        margin-bottom: 1.25rem !important;
        display: block;
    }
}
.image-hover-zoom:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

/*SAmple*/
.section {
    padding: 6rem 1.25rem;
}
.background-dark, .primary-color-dark .background-primary {
    background-color: #002633 !important;
}
.background-dark, .background-dark p, a.background-dark, a.background-dark:visited, a.background-dark:link, .background-dark a, .background-dark a:link, .background-dark a:visited, .background-dark a:hover, .background-dark a:active, .primary-color-dark .background-primary, .primary-color-dark .background-primary p, .primary-color-dark a.background-primary, .primary-color-dark a.background-primary:visited, .primary-color-dark a.background-primary:link, .primary-color-dark a.background-primary:visited, .primary-color-dark .background-primary a, .primary-color-dark .background-primary a:link, .primary-color-dark .background-primary a:visited, .primary-color-dark .background-primary a:hover, .primary-color-dark .background-primary a:active {
    color: #7697A2;
}
hr.break {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px 0;
}
.margin-top-bottom-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    display: block;
}
hr.break:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.text-size-12, .text-l-size-12 {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
p {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
}
.background-dark h1, .background-dark h2, .background-dark h3, .background-dark h4, .background-dark h5, .background-dark h6, .background-dark .h1, .background-dark .h2, .background-dark .h3, .background-dark .h4, .background-dark .h5, .background-dark .h6, .primary-color-dark .background-primary h1, .primary-color-dark .background-primary h2, .primary-color-dark .background-primary h3, .primary-color-dark .background-primary h4, .primary-color-dark .background-primary h5, .primary-color-dark .background-primary h6, .primary-color-dark .background-primary .h1, .primary-color-dark .background-primary .h2, .primary-color-dark .background-primary .h3, .primary-color-dark .background-primary .h4, .primary-color-dark .background-primary .h5, .primary-color-dark .background-primary .h6, .background-primary h1, .background-primary h2, .background-primary h3, .background-primary h4, .background-primary h5, .background-primary h6, .background-primary .h1, .background-primary .h2, .background-primary .h3, .background-primary .h4, .background-primary .h5, .background-primary .h6, .primary-color-primary .background-primary h1, .primary-color-primary .background-primary h2, .primary-color-primary .background-primary h3, .primary-color-primary .background-primary h4, .primary-color-primary .background-primary h5, .primary-color-primary .background-primary h6, .primary-color-primary .background-primary .h1, .primary-color-primary .background-primary .h2, .primary-color-primary .background-primary .h3, .primary-color-primary .background-primary .h4, .primary-color-primary .background-primary .h5, .primary-color-primary .background-primary .h6 {
    color: #fff;
}
.text-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
}
b, strong, .text-strong {
    font-weight: 700;
}
h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #152732;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.text-size-20, .text-l-size-20 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.margin-top-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
    display: block;
}
a.text-more-info:after {
    content: "\f006";
    font-family: mfg;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin-left: 0.625rem;
    transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
}
a.text-more-info {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    margin-top: 0.625rem;
}
.text-white-hover, .text-primary-hover, .text-dark-hover {
    transition: color 0.20s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: color 0.20s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: color 0.20s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.20s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.20s linear 0s;
}
.image-hover-zoom {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-hover-zoom img {
    transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.20s linear 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the viewport meta tag in the header?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```